# How to create extended (custom) file property in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

We have a proprietary file format which has embedded in it a `product-code`.

I am just starting down the path of "enabling the end-user to sort / filter by `product-code` when opening a file".

The simplest approach for us might be to simply have another drop-down in our customized Open File Dialog in which to choose a `product-code` to filter by.

However, I think it might be more useful to the end-user if we could present this information as a column in the details view for this file type - just as name, date-modified, type, size, etc., are also detail properties of a file-type (or perhaps generic to all files).

My vague understanding is that XP and prior Windows OSes embedded some sort of meta data like this in an alternate data stream in NTFS.  However, Starting in Vista Microsoft stopped using alternate data streams due to their dependence upon NTFS, and hence fragility (i.e. can't send via file attachment, can't move to a FAT formatted thumb drive, etc.)

Things I need to know but haven't figured out yet:

1. Is it possible / Is it practicable / how to create a custom extended file property for our file type that expresses the `product-code` to the Windows shell so that it can be seen in Windows Explorer (and hence File dialogs)?
2. If that is doable, then how to configure things so that the `product-code` column is displayed by default for folders containing our file type.

Can anyone point me to a good starting point on the above?  We certainly don't have to accomplish this by publishing a custom extended file property - but that *seems* like a sensible approach, in absence of any way to measure the costs of going this route.

If you have sensible alternative approaches to the problem, I'd be interested in those as well!

---

Just found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens

CRAP!  It seems I'm very late to the banquet, and MS has already removed this functionality from their shell: http://xpwasmyidea.blogspot.com/2009/10/evil-conspiracy-behind-customizable.html

Comment: Yes Microsoft removed this functionality in Vista. How many users do you need to support? There are various third-party file managers (including one my company makes, which I won't name as that would be a little blatant) which still support the IColumnProvider interface, so depending on your needs you may be able to specify the use of a third-party file manager as a solution for your users.

Comment: Here is the Vista way: [Windows Property System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest approach to developing a shell extension is to use a library made for the purpose.

I can recommend [EZShellExtension](http://www.ssware.com/ezshell/ezshell.htm) because I have used it in the past to add columns and thumbnails/preview for a custom file format for our company.